# In Django, can the choices defined in a model class be accessed elsewhere outside the model class?

Tags: python, django

I have the following model class

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    MOVIE_CHOICES = (
            ('SHAW', 'Shashank Redemption'),
            ('NIGHT', 'In the Heat of the Night'),
            ('GOD', 'The God Father'),
            ('INVIC', 'Invictus'),
            )  
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = MOVIE_CHOICES)
```

and I am writing the values to a database table.

When I query the database table, I will get the key back, e.g. I get `INVIC` back.

In my code I will need to get the value for the key, in this case `Invictus`.  To be able to do this, I need access to the data structure that holds the key-value pair.

How to access `MOVIE_CHOICES` by key outside of the model class?  Alternatively, can I use a dictionary to set values for choices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the human readable choice name by using instance method [get_{}_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Example for your model

```
movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=1)
movie.get_title_display()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a good technique described in Django [model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Example:

```
from django import models

class Movies(models.Model):
    MOVIE_SHAWSHANK = 'shaw'
    MOVIE_NIGHT = 'night'
    MOVIE_GODFATHER = 'god'
    MOVIE_INVIC = 'invic'

    MOVIE_CHOICES = (
        (MOVIE_SHAWSHANK, 'The Shawshank Redemption'),
        (MOVIE_NIGHT, 'In the Heat of the Night'),
        (MOVIE_GODFATHER', 'The God Father'),
        (MOVIE_INVIC', 'Invictus'),
    )  

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=MOVIE_CHOICES)
```

Now you can do the following to get 'The Shawshank Redemption' movie instance:

```
Movies.objects.filter(title=Movies.MOVIE_SHAWSHANK)
```

---

Another technique is to use `Enum` (if you are using Python 2.7 you have to install it: [Enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34))

Example:

```
from django import models
from enum import Enum

class Movies(models.Model):

    class MOVIE_CHOICES(Enum):
        shawshank = ('shaw', 'The Shawshank Redemption')
        night = ('night', 'In the Heat of the Night')
        godfather = ('god', 'The God Father')
        invic = ('invic', 'Invictus')

        @classmethod
        def get_value(cls, member):
            return cls[member].value[0]

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=[x.value for x in MOVIE_CHOICES]
    )
```

Now you can do the following to get 'The Shawshank Redemption' movie instance:

```
shawshank = Movies.MOVIE_CHOICES.get_value('shawshank')
Movies.objects.filter(flavor=shawshank)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  I am using Python 3.5 and will try to see if I can use the first technique you describe.